# How to calculate the sum of the bitwise xor values of all the distinct combination of the given numbers efficiently?

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, xor

Given n(n<=1000000) positive integer numbers (each number is smaller than 1000000). The task is to calculate the sum of the bitwise xor ( ^ in c/c++) value of all the distinct combination of the given numbers.

Time limit is 1 second.
For example, if 3 integers are given as 7, 3 and 5, answer should be 7^3 + 7^5 + 3^5 = 12.

My approach is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int num[1000001];
int main()
{
    int n, i, sum, j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum+=(num[i]^num[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

But my code failed to run in 1 second. How can I write my code in a faster way, which can run in 1 second ?

Edit: Actually this is an Online Judge problem and I am getting Cpu Limit Exceeded with my above code.

Comment: Your code performs XOR on each unordered pair of numbers from the given set, and sums those. Is that what you are trying to do?  "sum of the bitwise xor value of all the combination" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean distinct combination.

Comment: 7^3^5 is a combination but you didn't do that

Comment: Also your code potentially causes undefined behaviour by overflowing an int .  (using `unsigned int` for `sum` would fix that, although that may or may not slow down your program)

Comment: this problem requires only to calculate for every two integer distinct pair of combination

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute around 1e12 xors in order to brute force this. Modern processors can do around 1e10 such operations per second. So brute force cannot work; therefore they are looking for you to figure out a better algorithm.

So you need to find a way to determine the answer without computing all those xors.

Hint: can you think of a way to do it if all the input numbers were either zero or one (one bit)? And then extend it to numbers of two bits, three bits, and so on?

Comment: Good hint. I hope that would be enough for OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

This function grows quadratically (thanks @rici). At around 25,000 positive integers with each being 999,999 (worst case) the for loop calculation alone can finish in approximately a second. Trying to make this work with input as you have specified and for 1 million positive integers just doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Presumably the 1second time limit applies to the case where 1000000 inputs are read

Comment: Actually this is an Online Judge problem and I am getting Cpu Limit Exceeded with my code.

Comment: @Md.ShahidulIslam please provide a link to the problem so we can have a complete understanding.

Comment: Quadratically, not exponentially. All the same, the solution won't scale, so you need to find a better solution.

Comment: @rici oops! I wasnt thinking when I saw O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

When optimising your code you can go 3 different routes:

1. Optimising the algorithm.
2. Optimising the calls to language and library functions.
3. Optimising for the particular architecture.

There may very well be a quicker mathematical way of xoring every pair combination and then summing them up, but I know it not. In any case, on the contemporary processors you'll be shaving off microseconds at best; that is because you are doing basic operations (xor and sum).

Optimising for the architecture also makes little sense. It normally becomes important in repetitive branching, you have nothing like that here.

The biggest problem in your algorithm is reading from the standard input. Despite the fact that "`scanf`" takes only 5 characters in your computer code, in machine language this is the bulk of your program. Unfortunately, if the data will actually change each time your run your code, there is no way around the requirement of reading from stdin, and there will be no difference whether you use `scanf`, `std::cin >>`, or even will attempt to implement your own method to read characters from input and convert them into ints.

All this assumes that you don't expect a human being to enter thousands of numbers in less than one second. I guess you can be running your code via: `myprogram < data`.

Comment: Actually this is an Online Judge problem and I am getting Cpu Limit Exceeded with my code.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint in [Alan Stokes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31903020/2684539), you may have a linear complexity instead of quadratic with the following:

```
std::size_t xor_sum(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& v)
{
    std::size_t res = 0;

    for (std::size_t b = 0; b != 32; ++b) {
        const std::size_t count_0 =
            std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                          [b](std::uint32_t n) { return (n >> b) & 0x01; });
        const std::size_t count_1 = v.size() - count_0;
        res += count_0 * count_1 << b;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/2W5M2L).

Explanation:

- `x^y = Sum_b((x&b)^(y&b))` where `b` is a single bit mask (from `1<<0` to `1<<32`).
- For a given bit, with `count_0` and `count_1` the respective number of count of number with bit set to `0` or `1`, we have `count_0 * (count_0 - 1)` `0^0`, `count_0 * count_1` `0^1` and `count_1 * (count_1 - 1)` `1^1` (and `0^0` and `1^1` are `0`).